# How to stop div elements from being affected by text line breaks?

Tags: html, css, position

So when the window resizes it forces paragraph text to break onto more lines. That's fine, but I have a button at the bottom of the element that is being affected by the new lines. The new lines are pushing that element down. How can I stop this?

When I resize the window the text takes more height yes, which forces the button down in the container. I need the button to stay in place. Even if, hypothetically the text were to overlap with that button. I tried `position:absolute` on the button, but that didn't work.

Also, I don't want the buttons height or top/bottom margin to be affected by the amount of lines that the text occupies at all. even without a shrinking window the button on div2 is being pushed down because the text breaks to one more line than the other two divs.

Beyond that, I have 3 side by side Divs all with the same button at the bottom. My middle div has a bit more text in it that breaks onto one more line than the other 2...So div1 text has 3 lines, div2 text has 4 lines, and div3 text has 3 lines. The div2 button is slightly lower than the other two because that div has 4 lines of text instead of 3...how can I stop this?

```css
.container div p {
  font-family: $smallText;
  font-weight: 400;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0.625rem 1.875rem 0 1.875rem;
  color: $transparentWhite;
  font-size: 0.938rem;
}

.container button {
  position: relative;
  margin-left: 3.125rem;
  margin-top: 9rem;
  margin-bottom: 0.625rem;
  border-radius: 1.875rem;
  padding: 0.938rem;
  width: 9.375rem;
  border: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="sedans">
    <h1>SEDANS</h1>
    <p>Choose a sedan for its affordability and excellent fuel economy. Ideal for cruising in the city or on your next road trip.</p>
    <button class="button1" type="button">Learn More</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps a fixed-height layout with a flexible box for the text would do. This would keep the button at the bottom. The drawback is that you have to specify a container height, which is somewhat anathema to responsive development. Ideally you'll let the content flow naturally.

```css
.flex-wrapper {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 300px;
  background: pink; /* demo only */
  padding: 15px;
}

.flex-wrapper h1,
.flex-wrapper .button-box {
  flex: none;
  background: #ddd; /* demo only */
  overflow: hidden; /* demo only */
}

.flex-wrapper p {
  flex: auto;
  font-family: $smallText;
  font-weight: 400;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0.625rem 1.875rem 0 1.875rem;
  color: $transparentWhite;
  font-size: 0.938rem;
}

.container button {
  position: relative;
  border-radius: 1.875rem;
  padding: 0.938rem;
  width: 9.375rem;
  border: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="flex-wrapper sedans">
    <h1>SEDANS</h1>

    <p>Choose a sedan for its affordability and excellent fuel economy. Ideal for cruising in the city or on your next road trip.</p>

    <p class="button-box">
      <button class="button1" type="button">Learn More</button>
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: wait so I was right in not wanting to used fixed units. There is no way to just absolutely position the button without it being affected at all by the content above it without using fixed units?

Comment: Not really. Absolute positioning is with respect to the nearest non-statically positioned element. That container would also need a fixed height or some other constraint. Absolute positioning can be troublesome and should be avoided in favor of modern techniques like flexbox.

Answer (score 0):

It's not that the new line is affecting the element rather your 9rem for the button is the one that pushes down way too far. Please see my code:

```css
.container div p {
  font-family: $smallText;
  font-weight: 400;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0.625rem 1.875rem 0 1.875rem;
  color: $transparentWhite;
  font-size: 0.938rem;
}

.container button {
  position: relative;
  margin-left: 3.125rem;
  margin-top: 2rem;
  margin-bottom: 0.625rem;
  border-radius: 1.875rem;
  padding: 0.938rem;
  width: 9.375rem;
  border: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="sedans">
    <h1>SEDANS</h1>
    <p>Choose a sedan for its affordability and excellent fuel economy. Ideal for cruising in the city or on your next road trip.</p>
    <button class="button1" type="button">Learn More</button>
```

Comment: Okay yes that definitely helps, but not totally. Is there any way to completely eliminate the relationship between text lines and the positioning of the button? It is still pushing the button down when the window resizes, I'd like the button to be in the same place regardless of the the pText above it.

Comment: You can keep the button at the same place by giving a specific height to your outer div. However, you cannot prevent your new paragraph line from pushing the next sibling element. Is it possible to set your <div class="sedans"></div> height?

Comment: Yes I didn't think about setting a fixed height. I try to avoid fixed units because they scare me with all the responsive design stuff that I'm supposed to be learning lol but I guess height doesn't really matter. I'll try that.